# How to write a query in SQL which would return results when out of 7 flags 5 flags are true

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract customers from Oracle DB. Customer key being the primary key. Now there are 7 flags or attributes in DB whose value can either be 'Y' or 'N'.

I've to extract customers for whom out of these 7 flags any 5 flags are Y.

The only way I can think of it by making groups and using or clause.

Eg

Select * from Table_name where 
(flg_1='Y' and flg_2='Y' and flg_3='Y' and flg_4='Y' and flg_5='Y')
or (flg_2='Y' and flg_3='Y' and flg_4='Y' and flg_5='Y' and flg_6='Y')
or ....

and so on.

Is there any way which is less tedious to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate all the flag fields into one string field and replace the N values with a blank. Then get the resulting string length (it will be only Y values).

```
SELECT *
  FROM [table]
 WHERE length(replace(flg1 || flg2 || flg3 || flg4 || flg5 || flg6 || flg7, 'N', '')) >= 5
```

I'm sure there's a regular expression that could do this too but I'm not very good with writing regex.

Performance may be an issue here but it will get the job done.

Comment: You have to swap the first two parameters in call to replace

Answer (score 1):

This could be a quite self-explanatory way:

```
select *
from table_name
where case when flg_1 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end +
      case when flg_2 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when flg_3 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when flg_4 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when flg_5 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when flg_6 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end + 
      case when flg_7 = 'y' then 1 else 0 end >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is this one:

```
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(flg1 || flg2 || flg3 || flg4 || flg5 || flg6 || flg7, 'Y') => 5
```